# Only one nodename, but multiple values for nodeValue- DOMXPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, nodevalue, nodename

Why nodename prints "root", but nodeValue returns multiple and all the values in child nodes.

Running this code, the echo will return

> "The Name of the parent node is root Its value is Text value 11111
>   Empty text value 2222 space text value 3333 "

The second echo will return this

> "The child node is spaceIts value is space text value 3333"

```
<?php

$xmldoc=
    '<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>

<text>Text value 11111</text>
<none/>
<empty>Empty text value 2222</empty>
<space>space text value 3333 </space>
</root>';

$domdoc = new DoMDocument();
$domdoc->loadXML($xmldoc);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domdoc);

$rootNodeListParent = $xpath->query("//root");
$rootNodeParent = $rootNodeListParent[0];
echo "The Name of the parent node is " . $rootNodeParent->nodeName. " Its value is " . $rootNodeParent->nodeValue . "<br>";

$queryNodeList = $xpath->query("//space");
$nodeSpace = $queryNodeList[0];
 echo "The child node is " . $nodeSpace->nodeName. "Its value is " . $nodeSpace->nodeValue; //spacevalue ssddd
}
```

Comment: If I like to obtain only a text value inside the root..( I know that it does not have any text).. what should be the code for this..I was expecting nodeValue to be empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

"nodeValue returns multiple and all the values in child nodes"

Because that is what you asked for with `. $rootNodeParent->nodeValue .` there.

> The string-value of the root node is the concatenation of the
>   string-values of all text node descendants of the root node in
>   document order.
>
> "For every type of node, there is a way of determining a string-value
>   for a node of that type. For some types of node, the string-value is
>   part of the node; for other types of node, the string-value is
>   computed from the string-value of descendant nodes."

Ref https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#data-model